# Call to a member function pro_events() on null

Tags: laravel

Hello I'm trying to fix this issue where the error

> Call to a member function pro_events() on null

would not happen all the time. I'm not sure what's causing this.

Any idea how to prevent this error in case it would appear again? We just saw this error in the log but can't duplicate the issue. Thanks!

**Organizer.php** model

```
class Organiser extends MyBaseModel
{
    protected $rules = [
        'org_name'           => ['required', 'unique:organisers,name'],
        'email'          => ['required', 'email', 'unique:organisers'],
        'organiser_logo' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png', 'max:10000'],
        'terms_agreed'   => ['required'],
        'org_tags'   => ['required'],
    ];

    protected $messages = [
        'org_name.required'    => 'You must at least give a name for the event organiser.',
        'org_name.unique'      => 'Your desired organisation name is already taken.',
        'organiser_logo.max'   => 'Please upload an image smaller than 10Mb',
        'organiser_logo.size'  => 'Please upload an image smaller than 10Mb',
        'organiser_logo.mimes' => 'Please select a valid image type (jpeg, jpg, png)',
    ];

public function pro_events() {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ProEvent::class)->orderBy('event_date', 'asc');
}
```

**SomeController.php**

```
public function showPackageHome($organiser_id, $event_dummy = null, $event_id = null, $the_country = null, $package_type_id = null, $package_category_id = null)
    {
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
        $now        = Carbon::now();

        $cacheKey = md5(vsprintf('%s.%s', [
            $organiser_id,
            'organiser_cache'
        ]));

        $organiser = Cache::remember($cacheKey, 10, function() use ($organiser_id) {
            return Organiser::find($organiser_id);
        });

$cacheKey = md5(vsprintf('%s', [
            'event_list_cache'
        ]));

$events = Cache::remember($cacheKey, 1, function() use ($organiser, $now) {
          return $organiser->pro_events()
                            ->where("event_status", "live")
                            ->whereDate('event_date', '>=', $now->format("Y-m-d"))
                            ->orderBy('event_date', 'asc')
                            ->get();
          });
```

**ProEvent.php** model

```
class ProEvent extends MyBaseModel
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    protected $table   = 'pro_events';
```

Comment: Try and catch your assignment of data to `$events`, or simply throw an exception or ignore if `$events` is null.

Comment: how do you take the organizer? does it use soft deletes? maybe it is deleted or doesn't exist yet?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. yes but only the ProEvent model uses soft deletes(i edited the code above), does it relate to this issue?

Comment: Does the organizer depend on a filter or so? How do you get it? can you please include that code too?

Comment: Where's ```$organiser``` coming from ?

Comment: I just added some snippet on the code. Hope that helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must go up in the call stack to find where the organizer_id comes from. A possible reason would be that the admin/loggedIn person may change the route manually and try to load an organizer that doesn't exist.

If you have a route like `/organizer/{organizer_id}`, then you must make sure that the provided ID actually exists in db. One way to do it would be to use `findOrFail` instead of `find` and to catch the thrown exception in case the organizer doesn't exist.

```
public function showPackageHome($organiser_id, $event_dummy = null, $event_id = null, $the_country = null, $package_type_id = null, $package_category_id = null)
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $now        = Carbon::now();

    $cacheKey = md5(vsprintf('%s.%s', [
        $organiser_id,
        'organiser_cache'
    ]));


    $organiser = Cache::remember($cacheKey, 10, function() use ($organiser_id) {
        return Organiser::findOrFail($organiser_id);
    });

    $cacheKey = md5(vsprintf('%s', [
        'event_list_cache'
    ]));

    $events = Cache::remember($cacheKey, 1, function() use ($organiser, $now) {
    
         return $organiser->pro_events()
                        ->where("event_status", "live")
                        ->whereDate('event_date', '>=', $now->format("Y-m-d"))
                        ->orderBy('event_date', 'asc')
                        ->get();
     });
}
```

In your controller method you can actually catch the exception and display something to the user:

```
public function yourControllerMethod(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    // something more here

    try {
        $events = $this->showPackageHome($request->get('organizer_id'), /* the other parameters */);

        return $this->view(..., ['events' => $events]);
    } catch (Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $ex) {
        // The organizer couldn't be found
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['organizer-not-found' => 'The organizer could not be found'])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able to duplicate the issue by testing ```return Organiser::findOrFail('100');``` where organiser_id = 100 does not exists and the page just returned 404. This would suffice. Regards

Answer (score 0):

i think it's because the instance of Organizer where you called pro_events() function was null.